# how to use MySql server (downloaded on desktop) in android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

I want to use my database in MySQL server in android app

I have MySQL Server downloaded on my PC and it uses the 3306 port which is the default port. I need to be able to retrieve data from the database into my android app.
I downloaded XAMPP for PHP and got the error that same port cannot be used by both programs, so I changed the port to 3307 in every file (php.ini & the MySQL configurations). Finally, MySQL server is starting but now when I open PHPMyAdmin, I get these errors.

Is there a way other than using XAMPP, or should I uninstall MySQL server and reinstall XAMPP with default settings.

MySQL said: Documentation

> Cannot connect: invalid settings.  mysqli_real_connect():
> (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using
> password: NO)
>
> Connection for controluser as defined in your
> configuration failed.  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access
> denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>
> phpMyAdmin
> tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the
> connection. You should check the host, username, and password in your
> configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information
> given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: Why did you install two instances of MySQL? If you're installing MySQL separately, then simply don't run it from XAMPP. But phpMyAdmin comes with XAMPP by default - not with a standalone MySQL installation.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution,

1. Go to MySQL my.ini file and change port to 3007 wherever written.
   Open general settings of the connection and now change it to 3007.
2. Download  XAMPP with original settings.
3. Make a new connection in MySQL 8.0 downloaded in PC, call it xampp and write 3006 port. Test the connection, data will be updated according to the data present in PHPmyadmin. Now, you can use both PHPmyadmin and MySQL server workbench.